# How do identify the first character of a string as numeric or character in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to identify the first character in my data as numeric or character in SQL Server. I am relatively new to this and I don't know where to begin on this one.  But here is what I have done to this point. I had data that looked like this:

```
TypeDep
Transfer From 4Z2
Transfer From BZZ
Transfer From 123
Transfer From abc
```

I used the `right` function to remove the 'transfer from' and isolate the data I need to check.

```
UPDATE #decode
SET firstPartType = Right(z.TypeDep,17)
FROM #decode z
where z.TypeDep like 'TRANSFER FROM%'

firstPartType
4Z2
BZZ
123
abc
```

Now I need to add a column identifying the first character in the string. Producing the results below.

```
firstPartType   SecondPartType
4Z2             Numeric
BZZ             Alpha
123             Numeric
abc             Alpha
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `LEFT` and `ISNUMERIC()`, however be aware that `ISNUMERIC` thinks some additional characters such as `.` are numeric

```
UPDATE #decode
  SET SecondPartType =  
      CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(firstPartType, 1)) = 1 THEN'Numeric'
      ELSE 'Alpha'
      END 
FROM #decode;
```

Comment: I just tryed this and I am getting Alpha for all.  My guess is that because this was pulled out of a string (varchar) that I am having trouble identifying?

Comment: @AllyKat `ISNUMERIC` should work no matter what datatype it is, `VARCHAR` or `INTEGER` as long as it's a digit.

Comment: Nope, that shouldn't cause the problem. I can use this on a string `123B56` and still get `'NUMERIC'`

Answer (score 8):

A more robust approach is to use the limited regex functionality of sql server. ISNUMERIC will return false positives for single characters like .,$ to name a few.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN left(firstPartType, 1) like '[0-9]' THEN 'Numeric'
        ELSE 'Alpha'
    END AS SecondPartType
```

Comment: This solution worked better for me. Plus, if you were wanting to filter out the number and convert it regex is great for that.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(firstPartType, 1, 1)) = 1
        THEN 'Numeric'
    ELSE 'Alpha'
    END AS 'SecondPartType'
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this command

```
ISNUMERIC(LEFT(firstPartType, 1))
```

this return 1 if the first character is a Numbert
0 if isn't.

i think is all you need

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
UPDATE #decode
  SET SecondPartType =  
      CASE
          WHEN LEFT(firstPartType, 1) IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
               THEN'Numeric'
          ELSE 'Alpha'
      END 
FROM #decode;
```

Answer (score 0):

select ISNUMERIC(left('4ello world',1)) will be a "1" if the first character is a number.