# select rows that start with number to perform aggregation

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
create table model(model_no varchar);`
insert into model values('1&');`
insert into model values('2/12/20');`
insert into model values('a2');`
insert into model values(30);--i want this row`
insert into model values(3.1);--i want this row`
insert into model values(%20);`
```

rows could start with any special characters or might contain any special characters, I ultimately like to perform aggregation on model column.
I'm using snowflake database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find "numeric" values [TRY_CAST](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_cast.html) could be used:

> A special version of CAST , :: that is available for a subset of data type conversions. It performs the same operation (i.e. converts a value of one data type into another data type), but **returns a NULL value instead of raising an error when the conversion can not be performed.**

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(model_no AS NUMERIC(20,5)) AS model_no_num
FROM model
WHERE model_no_num IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

for SQL:

[How do identify the first character of a string as numeric or character in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950195/how-do-identify-the-first-character-of-a-string-as-numeric-or-character-in-sql/32950349)

for snowflare you can try:

```
a. isnumeric(38.5)
b. SELECT IS_REAL(TO_VARIANT(31)), IS_REAL(TO_VARIANT('hello'));
```

so read first character and use functions